# Back reference doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, regex

This works fine:

```
>>> re.search("([ab]).+?b",'dfebxxxxxxba').group()
'bxxxxxxb'
```

But the following gives None:

```
>>> re.search("([ab]).+?\1",'dfebxxxxxxba')
```

How do I find the text between a pair of 'a's or 'b's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly escape the back reference. The string `'\1'` equals to `'\x01'` which the regex parser won’t use as a back reference. If you escape it properly, it works:

```
>>> re.search('([ab]).+?\\1', 'dfebxxxxxxba')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 11), match='bxxxxxxb'>
```

Note that for most valid escape sequences in regular expressions, you don’t need to escape the backslash. For example `\s` is not a valid escape sequence in strings, so it will be passed on like that to the regex parser; some others like `\n` and `\t` don’t matter either because they are seen like that from the parser. And then there is `\b` (bell in strings, word boundary in regex) and the back references which need to be escaped.

The alternative is to use raw strings:

```
>>> re.search(r'([ab]).+?\1', 'dfebxxxxxxba')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 11), match='bxxxxxxb'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double `\\` in your back-references as follows:

```
re.search("([ab]).+?\\1",'dfebxxxxxxba').group();
'bxxxxxxb'
```